# How to connect Privoxy 3.0.21 with Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m?

Tags: google-chrome, privoxy

I want to connect Google Chrome to Privoxy for the purpose of blocking ads. How can I do that?

I found instructions describing Privoxy and Chrome connection online, but these all seem to apply to older versions and do not seem to be applicable anymore (there is no "wrench icon" etc).

I tried in Chrome:  Settings -> Show advanced settings -> Network -> Change Proxy Settings

When I click that button, a new window "Internet Properties" with several tabs opens. There I do not know how to proceed.

I should note that I want to use Privoxy only in connection with Chrome, I do *not* want tp set it up as a general proxy for other programs like Firefox etc.

--

Versions used:

Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m

Privoxy 3.0.21

Windows XP (don't know what version / service pack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must start it with the following command line switch:

> --proxy-server="localhost:8118"

To do this, right click chrome shortcut, select Properties, select Shortcut tab, and append it to the Target textbox after a typing  a space first.